# ReadProcessMemory - baseaddress VS location of the data from that process

Tags: .net, windows, 64-bit, readprocessmemory

I am trying to understand how a programms base address is related to it's data location on a 64bit Win10 OS. For example with Notepad. My (current) notepad process has a baseaddress of 0x00007ff687760000 and by using cheatengine I found the text to be located on 0x239F2E7E680. I was expecting the data to be on a fixed offset from/above the baseaddress and I am surprised to find it on a much lower address.

It was a hell of a job to get the ReadProcessMemory working correctly on 64bit, but I managed. I think I have probably read every post about it. But this last step remains a question for me. All I coud find is that the data-address = baseaddress + offset. BaseAddress is different each time. I have no problem to get the baseaddress. With CheatEngine I can find the data-address. But I simply dont understand why that address is lower then the baseaddress.

I hope someone can clarify this a bit.

Edit: What I am trying to do is to monitor a memory variable in another process and I do not want to first use CheatEngine to find the location.

Edit2: It seems that I can better rephrase the question to: What would be the correct way to monitor a variable in an other process from my own (C#) based program (On win10 - 64bit).

Comment: process have no any *baseaddress*. cheatengine found some string in heap and so what ?

Comment: The baseaddress applies to data that is in the program image, not dynamically allocated memory. You can use [VMMap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/vmmap) to verify.

Comment: Thats interesting comment! I am pretty sure it has to with my understanding of things. But so far I based my view on the examples I found, most of them stating that notepads data is always on a fixed offset from its baseaddress.... Even here on StackOverflow.

Comment: Memory allocated at runtime via `malloc` or `HeapAlloc` is typically from the process heap, but large blocks may be allocated directly via `VirtualAlloc`. The offset in the [PEB](http://www.geoffchappell.com/studies/windows/win32/ntdll/structs/peb/index.htm) of the handle (base address) for the process heap is known but not officially documented. Also note that a process can have multiple heaps created anywhere in memory. With the Universal C runtime library, C `malloc` uses the process heap, but MSVC used to create its own heap.